# esp8266 не хочет работать

Tags: arduino, serial, esp8266, arduino-uno

У меня esp8266 получает текст и отправляет на хост, но когда я отправляю текст из сириал есп не видит его.

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) { read_s = Serial.readString(); }
```

read_s получается всегда пустой

### arduino.uno

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2,INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
   boolean butt = digitalRead(2);
   Serial.println("est");
   delay(10000);
}

void temp(){

}

void led(){
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
}
```

### esp8266.uno

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

String wmail ="" ;
String read_s;
HTTPClient request; 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(100);     
    }
}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    read_s = Serial.readString();
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { 

    HTTPClient request; 
      String get_ = "https://dj-hook.herokuapp.com/api/send?token="+wmail+"&"+"text="+ read_s;;
      request.begin(get_);
       Serial.println("send mail");

    request.end();  
  }
}
```

---

Решил проблему взяв другую arduino ,
 **но решив попробовать со старой все заработало**

Comment: [Справка: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Извините, у меня esp8266 получает текс и отправляет на хост, но когда я отправляю текст из сириал есп не видит его. while (Serial.available() > 0) {

read_s = Serial.readString();

}

 read_s  получается всегда пустой

Comment: @ЕгорАвдеёж добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример в вопрос с помощью кнопки "[править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/934963/edit)"

Comment: Если подключить ESP к компу (например через usb-uart преобразователь), получает ли она сообщения от него? Как определяете, что полученная строка пустая - по отправленному запросу?

Comment: Не получает, пробовал

Comment: (У меня есп от амперки)

Comment: Кстати, если у вас всего одна кнопка и один светодиод, Arduino вам не нужна, тут достаточно просто esp8266.

Comment: Это тест , репозиторий замен гит

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, что у вас цикл чтения из serial неправильный:

1. Если нет символов для чтения, то цикл сразу пропускается, и отправляется HTTP запрос с неинициализированным значением из переменной `read_s`. В переменной может оказаться что угодно, только не то что вы ожидаете. В лучшем случае - пустая строка.
2. Если есть доступные для чтения символы, вы читаете их в переменную, при этом на каждой итерации затирая то что было прочитано ранее (я предполагаю, что цикл будет крутиться быстрее чем будут приходить данные по serial).

Попробуйте читать так:

```
void loop() {
    if(Serial.available() == 0) return;  // Если данных нет, сразу выходим из функции loop

    // Если есть данные - читаем их
    read_s = Serial.readString();

    // Дальше уже делаем с ними что хотим
    ...
}
```

## Обновлено

Отлаживать лучше поэтапно:

1. Прошиваем ESP8266 простым скетчем, который просто посылает обратно то что ему посылают (я предполагаю, что вы разобрались, как прошивать этот модуль):

   ```
   void setup() {
     Serial.begin(115200);
   }

   String read_s;

   void loop() {
       if(Serial.available() == 0) return;  // Если данных нет, сразу выходим из функции loop

       // Если есть данные - читаем их
       read_s = Serial.readString();

       // Дальше уже делаем с ними что хотим
       Serial.println(read_s);  // Например, отправляем обратно
   }
   ```
2. После прошивки оставляем модуль как есть подключенным к компьютеру, через serial monitor отправляем сообщения, если все работает, то видим, как они приходят обратно:

   [image: Скриншот 1]
3. Теперь нужно нужно протестировать взаимодействие между Arduino и ESP8266. Мы будем отправлять по serial сообщения на Arduino, а она будет пересылать сообщения на ESP8266, получать ответ, отправлять его на компьютер. При такой связке для взаимодействия с ESP8266 нужно использовать software serial (или Serial1, если у вас не Arduino Uno, а например Leonardo - см. [Hardware serial в статье по troyka wifi](http://wiki.amperka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B:troyka-wi-fi)), т.к. по одному serial интерфейсу нельзя взаимодействовать одновременно с двумя устройствами (компьютером и WiFi модулем).

   Пример скетча (модифицированный пример SoftwareSerialAT115200.ino [отсюда](http://wiki.amperka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B:troyka-wi-fi), 8-й пин Arduino должен быть подключен к пину TX wifi-модуля, 9-й пин - к RX):

   ```
   #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

   // создаём объект для работы с программным Serial
   // и передаём ему пины TX и RX
   SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9);

   void setup()
   {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     while (!Serial) {
     // ждём, пока не откроется монитор последовательного порта
     // для того, чтобы отследить все события в программе
     }
     Serial.print("Serial init OK\r\n");
     mySerial.begin(115200);
   }

   void loop()
   {
     // если приходят данные из Wi-Fi модуля - отправим их в порт компьютера
     if (mySerial.available()) {
       Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     }

     // если приходят данные из компьютера - отправим их в Wi-Fi модуль
     if (Serial.available()) {
       mySerial.write(Serial.read());
     }
   }
   ```

   [image: Скриншот 2]

   Если сообщения не возвращаются, проверьте соединения между Arduino и ESP8266.
4. Если все успешно, добавляем в прошивку WiFi модуля инициализацию WiFi и код отправки сообщений. Прошиваем, тут же тестируем, не отключая от компьютера.

   ```
   #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
   #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

   const char* ssid = "";
   const char* password = "";

   void setup() {
     Serial.begin(115200);
     WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);  // Полчаса убил на отладку из-за отсутствия этой строки
     WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
     while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
         Serial.println("Waiting for WiFi...");
         delay(100);     
     }
     Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
   }

   String token = "" ;
   String read_s;

   void loop() {
       if(Serial.available() == 0) return;  // Если данных нет, сразу выходим из функции loop

       // Если есть данные - читаем их
       read_s = Serial.readString();
       Serial.println("Got text '" + read_s + "'");  // Отчитываемся, что получили строку

       // Проверяем наличие соединения
       if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
          Serial.println("Cannot send: no WiFi connection");
          return; // Если нет соединения - выходим из функции
       }

       // Дальше код отправки запроса
       String url = "https://dj-hook.herokuapp.com/api/send?token=" + token + "&text=" + read_s;
       HTTPClient request;
       request.begin(url);
       Serial.println("send mail");
       request.end();
   }
   ```

   5. Снова подключаем модуль к Arduino как в пункте 3, тестируем. Если все работает, вносим изменения в прошивку Arduino, чтобы сообщение в WiFi модуль отправлялось по нажатию кнопки, тестируем, и т.д. пока не получим нужный результат.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/maos1x не видит

Comment: У вас wifi тройка модуль или WiFi slot?

Comment: Модуль у меня: http://amperka.ru/product/troyka-wi-fi

Comment: Ясно. Вечером протестирую.

Comment: @ЕгорАвдеёж, расписал подробно

Comment: На ней можно файфай трафик снимать?

Comment: @eri, смотря что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Имею ввиду monitor mode

Comment: @eri, если что-то вроде [этого](https://habr.com/ru/post/397741/), то наверное можно

Comment: А может быть проблема в есп?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mc4fe5

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mc4e46

Comment: @ЕгорАвдеёж, не знаю что у вас первый снимок демонстрирует, у вас там в скетче для esp код приема данных из serial закомментирован. Если у вас такой код залит в esp, то естественно она (он, оно?) данные принимать не будет.

Comment: Это я закоментировал , что бы проверь работает ли есп , но она даже запрос не посылает